# Problem with oritentation Google Vision object detection

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, google-cloud-vision, google-vision, google-cloud-automl

I'm training Google Vision for object and document recognition (fields in this document), but I came across a problem. When the image is rotated (90, 180 and up to 30, 50, 200 degrees) Vision does not recognize objects (fields). Is there any solution to this? Maybe rotate the markup during training (through the API because the Google interface is not possible as far as I know)? Or even create a label for each position (object_01, object_01_90, object_01_120 etc) and a label for each document step (document, document_90, document_120)?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Data argumentation, We can specify this during training in the tensorflow objection, check for the tag "data_augmentation_options" in the configuration file, ex - In the link below inline 159 horizontal flip is given 
 https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_inception_v3_pets.config.

You can add the below configuration to randomly rotate by 90 -

---

```
data_augmentation_options {
    random_rotation90 {
    }
  }
```

---

Comment: But how do I do it through Google Cloud Vision? Is there any way to do this through the api or the interface?

Comment: Well, I do not have access to google cloud, but you can check if there are any configuration files as shared above and updated the same.